# Google Sheets, difficulty with an IF statement in arrayformula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I've got the following arrayformula on my Google Sheet.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Balance";IF(M2:M="Cleared",(IF(len(G2:G),(sumif(row(G2:G),"<="&ROW(G2:G),G2:G)),)))})
```

Which mostly works, however If the cell in the M column doesn't say Cleared I'd like the Balance column to show the previous entry.  (This is for a ledger).

For example:

| Amount | Cleared | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100.00 | Cleared | 100.00 |
| 20.00 | Pending | 100.00 |
| 50.00 | Cleared | 150.00 |

any idea what formula I would use on the other side of the IF statement to accomplish this?

Comment: Where is the previous entry coming from? Please share a copy or sample sheet we can replicate, remove sensitive data if any.

Comment: oh man, i apologize. i must have my notifications not set up correctly.  I think i eventually found one source that indicated that ARRAYFORMULA cannot refer to itself.  I ended up going around it and just added another column to track.

Comment: Bot: [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.